# Confluent control-center -INFO Restored batch for store [MetricsAggregateStore] with topic-partition

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I'm running [confluent docker compose](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html) services and each time I start them with `docker compose up` I had to wait until tons of messages like this:

> control-center   | [2022-04-14 07:48:05,388] INFO Restored batch for
> store [MetricsAggregateStore] with topic-partition
> [_confluent-controlcenter-7-1-0-1-MetricsAggregateStore-changelog-0]
> with [100] records restored
> (io.confluent.controlcenter.streams.C3LoggingRestoreListener)

finish up loading.

I there a way to clear `MetricsAggregateStore` beforhand or clean it up? I don't really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `kafka-streams-application-reset` command to clean up the changelog topic, but you'd need to know the `application.id` of that internal process.